# I wonder if there is a way to know which button from a list i clicked

Tags: c#

Im coding in a windowsformapplication, c#
This is what i have done so far

```
    List<Button> list = new List<Button>();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j <= 13; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 13; i++)
            {
                Button ruta = new Button();
                ruta.Location = new Point(0+ (i * 50), 0 + (j * 50));
                ruta.Size = new Size(50, 50);
                ruta.AutoSize = false;
                ruta.Text = "";
                ruta.TabStop = false;
                list.Add(ruta);
                this.Controls.Add(ruta);
            }
        }
    }
```

What I now want is to be able to click on of these buttons and then change the text of a textbox to the index of the pressed button, I'm a real noob when it comes to C# so I have no idea what im doing atm.
What i thought about was something like

```
     private void ruta_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        txtBox.text = list.SelectedItemIndex();
      }
```

which obviously wont work since SelectedItemIndex() isnt a real method but just an example.

Comment: sender.... is the clue...

Answer (score 2):

You should look for the index of `sender` in your list. The sender will be the button that was clicked, and generally `sender` will be the control that triggered the event. Also don't forget to add the handler to the button as you do not do taht in your `for` right now.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    for (int y = 0; y <= 13; y++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 13; i++)
        {
            Button ruta = new Button();
            ruta.Location = new Point(0 + (i * 50), 0 + (y * 50));
            ruta.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            ruta.AutoSize = false;
            ruta.Text = "";
            ruta.TabStop = false;
            ruta.Click += ruta_click;
            list.Add(ruta);
            this.Controls.Add(ruta);
        }
    }
}

private void ruta_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtBox.Text = list.IndexOf((Button)sender) + "";
}
```